# MySQL ALTER TABLE on tables too large to duplicate

Tags: mysql

When adding a column to a MyISAM table, MySQL will Create>Copy>Drop>Rename.  I have a table which is sufficiently large that it cannot be duplicated in the server's remaining free space.  Attempting to add a column then results in the disk filling.  Time is not an issue here, neither is table availability, just disk space.

Short of copying the data to another server, truncating, altering, and copying back, is there a way to add a column to a MyISAM table *without* it creating a temporary table and duplicating all the data?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new, empty table, manually move the data over in chunks (INSERT into new, DELETE from old a certain number of rows), drop the old table and rename the new table. Essentially what MySQL does, but moving the data over instead of copying it, which should allow you to use less space.

Comment: I was afraid of this, but hoping for a less manual approach.  It may be what I end up doing.

Comment: Ultimately, this approach failed, filling the disk despite my slice size.  MySQL did not free up disk from the deleted rows.  Running OPTIMIZE to tell MySQL to free up the disk filled the disk.

Comment: I'm guessing it would have worked better with InnoDB, as the new table would reuse the free pages in the idb file. I'm afraid I don't have any other ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the only option for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general I try to keep enough free space to be able to rebuild my largest table. This allows me to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` when necessary.

Do you have another disk mounted on your server?

When space is too tight to rebuild a given table, my preferred workaround is to temporarily move some other table(s) to a separate disk volume. I do this by stopping MySQL, moving the relevant data files (MYD and MYI, or ibd), and then creating a symlink at the original location that points at the new location, and starting MySQL. Once the table rebuild is done I reverse that process to move the other table(s) back to their original location.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no additional storage attached to this host.

Comment: even if we have a separate disk mounted it's not practically possible to do so on a production server :(