# how to design database for ecommerce website?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, postgresql

how to create a database for products they don't share the same attributes; for example is it better to have one products table:

```
id|category|Description   |Mileage|Author_name |Print_length|Language|
1 |cars    |honda cvic ...|12315  |            |            |        |
2 |books   |Stranger's... |       |Albert Camus|208 page    |English |
```

or separate tables:
cars

```
 id|brand|Description   |Mileage|Body Type|yeasr|
 1 |Honda|honda cvic ...|12315  |sedan    |2015 |
```

Books:

```
id|Name          |Description   |Author_name |Print_length|Language|
1 |The Stranger's|Stranger's... |Albert Camus|208 page    |English |
```

please advise.

Comment: Probably neither of those approaches, I'm afraid. You probably want a product table with just an id and a name. Then, you want an attribute table with a product_id, attribute_name, attribute_value, where the attributes are things like description, author_name, etc. But this is a grossly oversimplified answer. If you are really setting out to build an e-commerce website and database from scratch, I highly suggest you do some serious research into the basic concepts of database design. I don't want to sound mean, but this question makes me think you need a lot more knowledge before you start.

Answer (score 1):

Either of the approaches you defined would work, yes. But as your website expands and grows, you are likely to encounter problems.

The first approach you suggested has a few issues.

1. When adding new product types, 'hats' for example, you will likely need to add additional columns to describe the attributes for hats that will have no relationship to cars or books. This will lead to a sparsely populated table. i.e. each product/row will only have data for a subsection of the columns. This can have an impact on the storage required to store the data. (Does your database allocate space for these blank columns? If so, your space requirements could balloon quickly.)
2. When making modifications to your table (adding a column, renaming a column, dropping a column) there could be a huge performance penalty while performing the modification, as a MyISAM implementation copies the entire table to a temp table, drops the old table, and renames the temp table to the original table. (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760600/mysql-alter-table-on-tables-too-large-to-duplicate))

Your second approach helps to address both issues described above, but introduces new problems worth considering.

1. If your strategy is to create a new table per product type, this can quickly explode in a massive number of similar-but-slightly-different tables. Imagine if Amazon or Newegg took this approach - the table count would approach absurdly large numbers and maintenance would become a problem. In addition, all new products would require modifications to the database structure, as well as the webapp code sitting on top of the database.
2. Tuning indexes to maintain performance on thousands of product tables seems like an unnecessarily burdensome task.

Solutions:

As another poster suggested, starting with two simple tables - a 'product' table (ID, name) and an 'attribute' table (ID, ProductID, Name, Value), would address a lot of the complexity and allow for new products to be launched **without modification to the underlying table structure** which is a huge win. This approach will require the use of indexes in order to optimize performance, but since only two tables will be used, you can better focus your efforts.